# Duplicate even number from first array into another array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested

I have an issue where it seems like when I try to display my new array full of even numbers from the first array, it only outputs the last value? I don't see where the problem lies within the nested for loop inside my GetEven method?

```
package allevenproj;

import java.util.*;

public class AllEvenProj {

static int Read(int[] arr) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter arr[%d]: ", i);
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("There are %d even numbers\n", count);
    return count;
}

static int[] GetEven(int[] arr, int count) {

    int[] evenArr = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                evenArr[j] = arr[i];

            }
        }
    }
    return evenArr;
}

static void Print(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    int a = Read(arr);
    Print(GetEven(arr, a)); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'are getting only the last value because due to the inner for loop in the `GetEven` method: every time you do a full inner loop (you do it for every number in `arr`) you rewrite the whole `evenArr`.
So the fix is removing the inner loop:

```
static int[] getEven(int[] arr, int count) {

    int[] evenArr = new int[count];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenArr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return evenArr;
}
```

By the way, methods name should be lowercase. [Naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Ruben said the problem is in your loop. I took the liberty to refactor your code a bit just to show you a better approach to the problem

```
package allevenproj;

import java.util.*;

public class AllEvenProj {
    static int[] read(int size) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter arr[%d]: ", i);
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    static void print(int[] arr) {
        System.out.printf("There are %d even numbers\n", arr.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        print(Arrays.stream(read(size)).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).toArray());
    }
}
```